# Library directory in iOS using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, file-manager

I'm very confused. I want to store few user files, but not docs. I'm using:

```
static var directory: URL {
    get { 
       return FileManager.default.urls(for: .libraryDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0].appendingPathComponent("Caches").appendingPathComponent("OnlineFiles") 
    }
}
```

Always the same. Every time I launch the app I get different URL.
Am I doing something wrong? Is there some magic switch in project file which I need to set?

Once it's something like:

> file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/4547EF22-EB33-4B65-9772-67ED7870E3E9/Library/Caches/OnlineFiles

Other time it's:

> file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/83C8CDD7-B4D0-48B2-8A8E-9BD48C5D1754/Library/Caches/OnlineFiles

This string between /Application/ and /Library/ seems to be random. How to store files in one location when I can access them later when opening app second time?

[EDIT]: how to get path which is not changed every time I update app?

Comment: Your code is fine. This is working as expected. Why is this a problem?

Comment: Every time the application is updated (which also happens when you reinstall app from Xcode), it is put into a different directory. Just don't use absolute URLs.

Comment: The "string between /Application/ and /Library/" is the apps UID

Comment: Edit - why do you care if it changes? It's supposed to change. Instead of asking how to avoid something that is working properly, explain what issue you are actually having with this.

Answer (score 2):

This is apple's security mechanism.Every time you restart the APP, apple sandbox path of APP to encryption, to prevent access to other programs.The encryption keys inside the APP.So before the end of the program, no matter where to access the APP sandbox, return to the path are the same.If you want to know more, you can look at apple's sandbox mechanism.

Comment: That's nice explanation but not an answer. Answer is provided in comment by Sulthan: "don't use absolute URLs", always use:   currentLibraryDirectory.appendingPathComponent(relativePath)